# extract values from Xml File

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to extract the following values from an xml file:
- 
- 
The xml file is represented as follow:

```
 <ENVELOPE_CONTENT>
   <DOCUMENTS>
    <DOCUMENT>
      <IDX>1529</IDX> 
      <ENTITY_PRIORITY>5</ENTITY_PRIORITY> 
      <CLD_COD>MAGAZINE</CLD_COD> 
      <CLD_DESC>Revues, magazine</CLD_DESC> 
      <CATEGORY>OTHER</CATEGORY> 
      <TIF_FILENAME>revues, magazine_1529_si.tif</TIF_FILENAME> 
      <COMMENT /> 
      <REJECT_MESSAGES /> 
      <PAGES>
       <PAGE>
         <PAGIDX>3375</PAGIDX> 
         <POSITION>1</POSITION> 
         <TIFNAME>87771593-2FD4-4803-8736-E2C1A898A96B_002.tif</TIFNAME> 
         <JPEGNAME>87771593-2fd4-4803-8736-e2c1a898a96b_001.jpg</JPEGNAME> 
       </PAGE>
       <PAGE>
        <PAGIDX>3376</PAGIDX> 
        <POSITION>2</POSITION> 
        <TIFNAME>87771593-2FD4-4803-8736-E2C1A898A96B_004.tif</TIFNAME> 
        <JPEGNAME>87771593-2fd4-4803-8736-e2c1a898a96b_003.jpg</JPEGNAME> 
      </PAGE>
      <PAGE>
        <PAGIDX>3377</PAGIDX> 
        <POSITION>3</POSITION> 
        <TIFNAME>87771593-2FD4-4803-8736-E2C1A898A96B_006.tif</TIFNAME> 
        <JPEGNAME>87771593-2fd4-4803-8736-e2c1a898a96b_005.jpg</JPEGNAME> 
      </PAGE>
      <PAGE>
        <PAGIDX>3378</PAGIDX> 
        <POSITION>4</POSITION> 
        <TIFNAME>87771593-2FD4-4803-8736-E2C1A898A96B_008.tif</TIFNAME> 
        <JPEGNAME>87771593-2fd4-4803-8736-e2c1a898a96b_007.jpg</JPEGNAME> 
      </PAGE>
      </PAGES>
     </DOCUMENT>
    </DOCUMENTS>  </ENVELOPE_CONTENT>
```

I am using the following c#code to extract the values

```
string xmlText = File.ReadAllText(f);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
XmlNodeList parentNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DOCUMENT");

List<string> p = new List<string>();
string classe = "";
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
{
     classe = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("CLD_COD").InnerText;

 }//end foreach
```

I managed to extract the Value from CLD_COD But i can't manage to extract the values in "TIFNAME"

How can i iterate through the nodes to extract them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is a lot easier with the newer XML API Linq-2-XML (XLinq).

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xmlText);  // or directly .Load(fileName)

List<string> tifNames = root.Descendants("TIFNAME").Select(e => e.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you Henk. This solution is very simple. It worked fine With the solution of Lazy

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(f);
var cldCod = (string)xdoc.Descendants("CLD_COD").FirstOrDefault();
var names = from p in xdoc.Descendants("PAGE")
            select (string)p.Element("TIFNAME");
```

Another option is XPath extensions. You can specify exact path to elements to avoid whole xml lookup:

```
var root = xdoc.Root;
var cldCod = (string)root.XPathSelectElement("DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/CLD_COD");
var names = from n in root.XPathSelectElements("DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/PAGES/PAGE/TIFNAME")
            select (string)n;
```

Comment: To convert names to List<string> Just names.ToList(). Thank you so much for your fast answers.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this also

```
        string xmlText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\virens\\Desktop\\Testxml.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
        XmlNodeList parentNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DOCUMENT");
        IEnumerator testnodes = parentNode[0].ChildNodes.GetEnumerator();

        List<string> p = new List<string>();
        string classe = "";

        while (testnodes.MoveNext())
        {

            XmlNode node = (XmlNode)testnodes.Current;

            if (node.Name == "TIF_FILENAME")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yai I got it");
                Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use the older XmlDocument, you can try something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
XmlNodeList xn = doc.SelectNodes("/ENVELOPE_CONTENT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/PAGES/PAGE/TIFNAME");

foreach (XmlNode xnode in xn)
{                   
    //extract values here
    Console.WriteLine(xnode.InnerText);
}
```